# Interactive transition like Google Maps (iOS)

Tags: ios, google-maps, uiscrollview, draggable, transition

I want to achieve something very close to what Google Maps (iOS) does and I have some doubts.

But first, a better explanation and things to take into account:

-------------- ANSWER --------------

Thanks to Jugale's contribution, here's a repository so everybody can download and test everything out.

https://github.com/vCrespoP/VCSlidingView

-------------- ORIGINAL QUESTION -----------

- You tap in a point inside the map, a view comes in from the bottom but then when you interact with that summary view:
- Notice when pulling just a bit, the navigation bar already has set.
- When you have scrolled it to the top, you can continue scrolling and the inner scrollview will continue scrolling.
- When you 'reverse' the action to dismiss the view, the PanGesture doesn't mess up with the inner scrollView (same for the other way, scrollView VS dismiss)

Here it is in action:
[image]

Doubts:

- I've tried to do it as an interactive transition (UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition) and separating Map from Details in 2 controllers but I'm having troubles with the UIPanGesture interfering with the scrollView.
- Maybe it's better to do it as a subview and handle everything there? More or less like MBPullDownController (Although it has some issues with iOS8) -> https://github.com/matej/MBPullDownController

So, anybody knows any framework, has done it, or knows how to do this in a good way?

Thank you for your time :D

Comment: I.. Actually did this recently (if I'm understanding you correctly), and it was *really* ugly. The solution for the scrollview/pan problem was to forward relevant events from `scrollview.panGestureRecognizer` to the class that handled the main pan when the scrollview was scrolled right to the top

Comment: Could you please post that specific code to get a clear idea? Or all if you're feeling merciful today :P 

Did you use interactive transitions, or a subview in just one controller?


I also saw that in the framework I linked, it uses internally "hitTest" and then it forwards the touch event to one controller or another but I don't know if this is possible in interactive transitions.

Comment: It's work code, so I don't think I can post it all.. Also I don't have it with me at the moment - I'll try and filter the relevant parts and post an answer ASAP. As for the other questions: the overlay is just a UIView subclass, and the transition uses `UIKitDynamics`

Comment: Ok, that's helpful Jugale. I am worried about my code and how each controller should have it's responsibility, don't want to put everything inside one. The framework is using 3 controllers, the container, the front and back controller. So you think it's better that way than interactive transitions, right? Thank you very much for your answers and help, I look forward to seeing your code if you're able. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through my implementation it seems the following are true:

1. I have a subclass of `UIViewController` that is the view controller
2. I have a subclass of `UIView` that is the overlay (and henceforth with the known as "the overlay") (actually for me this is a `UIScrollView` because it needs to go sideways too, but I'll try and filter out the unnecessary code)
3. I have another subclass of `UIView` that loads the overlay's content ("the content wrapper")
4. The content wrapper has a `UIScrollView` property, in which all other views are loaded ("the content view")

The view controller is responsible for initializing the overlay, setting it's initial frame (where the height is the height of the screen) and passing content to it, nothing more.

From it's `-initWithFrame` method, the overlay sets itself up with a `UIDynamicItemBehavior`. It also creates some `UICollisionBehavior` objects: one at the top of the screen and one below the bottom of the screen at just the right y position for the top of the overlay to be partially visible (as seen in the first frame of your GIF). A `UIGravityBehavior` is also set up to keep the overlay sitting on the lower collision boundary. Of course, `_animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc...` is set up too.

Finally:

```
_pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan)];
_pan.delegate = self;
_pan.cancelsTouchesInView = FALSE;
```

The overlay class also has some other helpful methods such as changing the gravity's direction so that the overlay can appear to snap to the top or bottom of the screen.

The `_pan` handler uses a `UISnapBehavior` to keep the overlay moving dynamically up and down the screen underneath the user's finger:

```
- (void)handlePan
{
    [self handlePanFromPanGestureRecogniser:_pan];
}

- (void)handlePanFromPanGestureRecogniser:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan
{
    CGFloat d = [pan velocityInView:self.superview.superview].y;

    CGRect r = self.frame;
    r.origin.y = r.origin.y + (d*0.057);

    if (r.origin.y < 20)
    {
        r.origin.y = 20;
    }
    else if (r.origin.y > [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - PEEKING_HEIGHT)
    {
        r.origin.y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - PEEKING_HEIGHT;
    }

    if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        [self panGestureEnded];
    }
    else if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        [self snapToBottom];
        [self removeGestureRecognizer:_tap];
    }
    else
    {
        [_animator removeBehavior:_findersnap];
        _findersnap = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self snapToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(r), CGRectGetMidY(r))];
        [_animator addBehavior:_findersnap];
    }
}

- (void)panGestureEnded
{
    [_animator removeBehavior:_findersnap];

    CGPoint vel = [_dynamicSelf linearVelocityForItem:self];
    if (fabsf(vel.y) > 250.0)
    {
        if (vel.y < 0)
        {
            [self snapToTop];
        }
        else
        {
            [self snapToBottom];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (self.frame.origin.y > (self.superview.bounds.size.height/2))
        {
            [self snapToBottom];
        }
        else
        {
            [self snapToTop];
        }
    }

}
```

The content wrapper listens for scroll events generated by the content view:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //this is our fancy way of getting the pan to work when the scrollview is in the way
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0 && _dragging)
    {
        _shouldForwardScrollEvents = TRUE;
    }

    if (_shouldForwardScrollEvents)
    {
        if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(theContentWrapper:isForwardingGestureRecogniserTouches:)])
        {
            [_delegate theContentWrapper:self isForwardingGestureRecogniserTouches:scrollView.panGestureRecognizer];
        }
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    _dragging = FALSE;//scrollviewdidscroll must not be called after this

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0 || _shouldForwardScrollEvents)
    {
        if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(theContentWrapperStoppedBeingDragged:)])
        {
            [_delegate theContentWrapperStoppedBeingDragged:self];
        }
    }

    _shouldForwardScrollEvents = FALSE;
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    _dragging = TRUE;
}
```

As you can see, when the bool `shouldForwardScrollEvents` is `TRUE` then we send `scrollView.panGestureRecognizer` to the content wrapper's delegate (the overlay). The overlay implements the delegate methods like so:

```
- (void)theContentWrapper:(TheContentWrapper *)contentWrapper isForwardingGestureRecogniserTouches:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)contentViewPan
{
    [self handlePanFromPanGestureRecogniser:contentViewPan];
}

- (void)theContentWrapperStoppedBeingDragged:(TheContentWrapper *)contentWrapper
{
    //because the scrollview internal pan doesn't tell use when it's state == ENDED
    [self panGestureEnded];
}
```

Hopefully at least some of this is useful to someone!

Comment: I'll try this today and let you know how it went, then I'll mark it as correct :D I have to say how thankful I am for the time you took to do this for a completely stranger. Thank you so much Jugale!

Comment: I'm having some problems putting the code together. I have made a repository with a minimum project and your code, but there are a lot of variables missing and I didn't completely understand the interaction between those views (overlay + content view). If you'd like to contribute, you are more than welcome
https://github.com/vCrespoP/VCSlidingView

Comment: @Sento always glad to help - I'll take a look tomorrow!

Comment: @Sento https://github.com/Jugale/VCSlidingView-test is working for me. Really really sorry, it's a bit of a mess, but shouldn't be too hard to clean up. Let me know how you go!

Comment: Perfect Jugale, thanks for your time once again! 
Nice code,everything working :D :D

Comment: @Jugale i have checked ur sliding view. one question, if i am to reduce the size of panel, how would i do it? in ur sample its going all the way to top, let's say i want to make the panel of size 300 only. If i set boundry upperwall it works however it starts dragging right and left

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Not sure what you mean - I just ran my sample and it seems it doesn't go all the way to the top (stays below the status bar)